# zlib compiling on windows 7 (x64)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, collada

I had compiled zlib on my comp to compile libxml (for collada dom).
But I don't know which directories are supposed to be /lib and /include at compiling libxml.
Sorry for my English and my noobinity :) Thx for the answers and the worthy time You have spent on answering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whichever folder the zlib header files are in is the folder to add into the list of include paths when compiling libxml. Similarly the folder that holds your compiled zlib library should go into the linker's list of search directories. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh thank, the include dir problem solved by you :)
But I can not find zlib.dll or zlib.lib :(

Comment: user408141: Are you sure that you successfully built zlib?

Comment: I really dunno :S
I have successfully compile every VS project at contrib/vstudio.